# writing a file list to a text file but don't want the directory name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a quick batch program that will either copy the names of the files in a folder or that folder and the sub folders. The issue I'm having is: I don't want the directory names.

Here is my code:

```
if %_JOB%! NEQ ! set _JOB=%_JOB%-
if %_FOLDERS%! == y! set _FOLDERS=Y

echo Created %cdate% > "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%_JOB%PDFlist.txt"
echo Folder: %CD% >> "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%_JOB%PDFlist.txt"
if %_FOLDERS%! == Y! (
  echo Include sub-folders: True >> "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%_JOB%PDFlist.txt"
) ELSE (
echo Include sub-folders: False >> "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%_JOB%PDFlist.txt"
)
echo. >> "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%_JOB%PDFlist.txt"
echo ============================== BEGIN LIST ============================== >> "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%_JOB%PDFlist.txt"
if %_FOLDERS%! == Y! (
  dir *.pDF /s /b /A-D-H >> "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%_JOB%PDFlist.txt"
) ELSE (
  dir *.pdf /b /A-D-H >> "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%_JOB%PDFlist.txt"
)
echo =============================== END LIST =============================== >> "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%_JOB%PDFlist.txt"
cls
echo.&echo List Generated!
echo.&echo.&ECHO.Press ANY key to EXIT and view your file
PAUSE>NUL
start notepad "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%_JOB%PDFlist.txt"
EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not recurse into subfolders, then the bare format switch (`/b`) is sufficient. If you recurse with the same switch, however, you get the whole path.

With Command Extensions enabled, you can use the following to filter out just the filenames:

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir *.pdf /s /b /A-D-H') do @echo %%~nxF
```

See `help for` for more info, but what the above does, is take the output of the `dir …` command and for each item then print out just the name and extension (effectively dropping drive and path).